# how to send object list as response to an ajax request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working in web site don using **.net MVC**.

In my home page I have area to list some statistics of clients.
Since these values are changing frequently I need to poll data from server and I have planed to use **AJAX** requests to server continuously after the some interval.

My question is: Is it possible to send list of client object as response to ajax request.
I have a class called `Client` and I am looking whether I can send `List<Client>` as response)

Can anybody please provide me guide lines or some sample links.

Comment: Did you look at Json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a JsonResult method in your controller which returns the list of objects as json and then you can call the method using ajax.

So your method would look something like:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetClients(//any arguments sent from the client here)
{
    var clients = //code to get clients
    return Json(new {clients = clients}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then make the ajax request in your view using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: //url to access GetClients method e.g. '/home/GetClients',
    method: 'GET',
    data: //any arguments you want to send to the server
    success: function(resp){
        var clients = resp.clients;//get list of clients from the response
        //do stuff with the list of clients
    },
    error: {//code to handle what happens if an error occurs}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try
model:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public DateTime Year { get; set; }
    public List<Passanger> Passangers { get; set; }
}

public class Passanger
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

view:

```
@model Car
@using(Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "my-form" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Manufacturer)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Model)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Year)

    for(int i = 0, i < Model.Passangers.Count(), i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Passangers[i].Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Passangers[i].Name)
    }

    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="form-submit" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '#form-submit', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "Car/AddCar",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('form#my-form').serialize(),
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert(data);
                // put the data in the container where you have the form.
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281660/mvc-3-with-ajax-submit-complex-object-to-controller)

Comment: I need to sen objects list from server to client as response to ajax request. In your solution you are sending serialized form client to server.

Answer (score 0):

serialize the list to json,
This is easier with the json.net  library.

http://json.codeplex.com/

at the web page,you can do whatever you would normal operate on json data.